# Replace substring ", **" in string

Tags: java, regex, string

I have string "the best, **i have". I want to replace ", **" to " ", my code

```
string str = "the best, **i have";
string a = str.replace(", \\**", " ");
```

but if string is "the best, she have money" then string replace to "the best she have money".

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not escaping the second asterisk properly.

The regular expression that you give means `", "` literally, followed by any number of `"*"` characters.

The correct regex string should be `", \\*\\*"`.